# Controlling a Selenium WebDriver with Keypresses in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, python-multithreading

I'm working on a Python script using Selenium to automate tasks on a website. In my script, I have a loop that performs various actions on the web page, such as checking inputs and clicking buttons. But I want to be able to manually make the driver restart the program by going back to the main page and restarting the loop. I think this needs to be done using muiltiple threads, because I cannot stop the main loop to check for keyboard inputs since the loop can take minutes to finish and restart. The driver should remain the same between threads.

I've attempted to use the `multiprocessing` module, as it allows thread termination with `proc.terminate()`, unlike the `threading` module. However, I've encountered an issue: `multiprocessing` cannot directly share a global variable (the Selenium WebDriver) between processes.
(I know it's not a great idea to abruptly stop threads, but since this is a manual input, it should be able to be stopped at any time.)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("Starting program...")
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=programThread)
    proc.start()

    is_pressing = False

    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+f10'):
            if not is_pressing:
                print("Resetting Program...")
                is_pressing = True
                proc.terminate()
                if resetProgram(driver):
                    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=programThread)
                    proc.start()
                else:
                    print("Could not reset program, exiting...")
                    exit()
            continue
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+f9'):
            if not is_pressing:
                print("Stopping Program...")
                is_pressing = True
                proc.terminate()
            continue
        is_pressing = False
```

My question is: How can I enable manual input to restart the script without disrupting the ongoing automation loop? Should I use multiprocessing, and if so, how can I address the issue of sharing the WebDriver between processes?

Comment: i dont understand the question....  do you want to terminate one thread and keep the other threads running ?

Comment: I want the thread running the driver and performing actions on the website to stop and restart, while the driver stays open and waits for instructions, until the thread has restarted and continues to give instructions to the WebDriver object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I think my original idea might be impossible to implement correctly, but I have found a workaround by just not using the same driver and terminating the driver's process and killing the still open chrome window using psutil

```
parent_processes = []
for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'connections']):
    if proc.name() != 'chrome.exe':
        continue
    process = psutil.Process(proc.info['pid'])
    
    if process.ppid() not in parent_processes:
        parent_processes.append(process.ppid())

for parent in parent_processes:
    parent_process = psutil.Process(parent)
    if parent_process.name() == 'chrome.exe':
        if "VSCODE_NONCE" in parent_process.environ():
            print("Terminating dead selenium instance...")
            parent_process.terminate()
```

This might not be the most elegant solution but it works.
After this I simply recreate the original thread and everything restarts as expected